# Showing Recent Messages Undefined symbol: _OBJC_CLASS_$_FMDatabaseQueue

Tags: flutter

ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/ahmadmerie/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-dwsnagfwrbrqcfdmlupmrbmuveov/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/FMDB/FMDB.framework/FMDB, building for iOS-armv7 but attempting to link with file built for iOS-arm64
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
"*OBJC_CLASS*$_FMDatabaseQueue", referenced from:
objc-class-ref in SqflitePlugin.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

after I upgrade to flutter 2.0.1

Comment: Solved this yet?

Comment: did you resolve this issue ??